# Java ObjectInputStream with multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I have a project in Java where I use sockets to move objects between a server and a client.

On the server multithreading is used to make sure multiple clients can connect to the server.

When I connect to the server from the client it works the first time, but after that I keep getting a `java.io.StreamCorruptedException`. 
After some reading it looks like this has something to do with a new connection that is created every time, and that makes the stream corrupt.

At this moment I am unable to figure out by myself how I can fix this so I home one of you can help me out here.

On the server there are 2 classes:

The main class that starts the server and creates the threads

```
package AexServer;

import AexServerMock.MockEffectenbeurs;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;

public class AexBannerServerSockets {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        boolean listening = true;
        IEffectenBeurs effectenbeurs = new MockEffectenbeurs();

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 4444.");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        while (listening) {
            Thread t = new Thread(new AexBannerServerSocketsRunnable(serverSocket.accept(), effectenbeurs));
            t.start();
        }
        serverSocket.close();
    }
}
```

And a class that controls the sockets

```
public class AexBannerServerSocketsRunnable implements Runnable {

    private Socket socket = null;
    private IEffectenBeurs effectenbeurs = null;
    ObjectOutputStream oos;
    AEXBannerProtocol ABP;
    IMessage outputLine;
    PrintWriter out;
    BufferedReader in;

    public AexBannerServerSocketsRunnable(Socket socket, IEffectenBeurs effectenbeurs) {
        try {
            this.socket = socket;
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            this.effectenbeurs = effectenbeurs;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AexBannerServerSocketsRunnable.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            String inputLine;
            ABP = new AEXBannerProtocol(effectenbeurs);

            this.println(null);

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                this.println(inputLine);
                if (outputLine.getMessage().equals("Bye")) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            out.close();
            in.close();
            socket.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void println(String inputLine) {
        try {
            outputLine = ABP.processInput(inputLine);
            oos.writeObject(outputLine);
            out.println(oos);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AexBannerServerSocketsRunnable.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

On the client side I have a very simple Main class

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {    
            String input;
            PrintWriter out;
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 4444);
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

            IMessage result = (Message) ois.readObject();
            System.out.println(result.getMessage());

            while (true) {
                input = scanner.nextLine();
                out.println(input);

                result = (Message) ois.readObject();
                System.out.println(result.getMessage());
            }

        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
}
```

When this class starts it shows the result of the first `System.out.println(result.getMessage());`

After that I can enter a string in the command line as a command to the server.

When I do that I get the next error:

```
mrt 11, 2017 4:27:58 PM Client.Main main
SEVERE: null
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 6A
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1563)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
    at Client.Main.main(Main.java:65)
```

Why does this not work and how can I solve this?

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense: you're using both an ObjectOutputStream and a PrintWriter on the same socket outputstream. And you write null using the OOS, then you write the toString() of the ObjectOutputStream itself to this unique socket output stream. I can't understand the point of doing that. And BTW, the client only expects to receive objects, not text.

Comment: You should post code that we can compile/use. I tried to change this a little bit but there are classes that I don't have: AexServerMock.MockEffectenbeurs